# pass VT_ARRAY to COM object

Tags: c#, c++, com, ref, comobject

I have a COM object which exports a function like this:

```
SetValue(Guid paramID, ref object paramValue);
```

For a specific Guid, I should pass **paramValue** as "VT_ARRAY | VT_INT" as said in the document. Indeed I should pass 4 integers which is 16 bytes in total (4x4). It's simple in C++ but I couldn't do it in C#. How can I pass VT_ARRAY from C# to COM?

I tried this:

```
object[] values = new int[4];
// set values[0]-[4] some numbers
comObj.SetValue(new Guid(Guid_str), ref values);
```

But it says: Cannot convert **ref object[ ]** parameter to **ref object**.

Also I tried to create a struct and pass it to the function but it causes runtime error. Maybe I couldn't define it correctly.

Comment: int[] values = new int[4];  object arg = values;

Comment: Use OleView to open the COM DLL as type library and show the IDL signature of the `SetValue` method.